# how to query RDS SQL Server database in AWS lambda using python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to AWS RDS SQL Server instance to query table from AWS Lambda using python script. But, I am not seeing any AWS api so when I try using "import pyodbc" seeing the below error.

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyodbc'

Connection:

```
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                        "Server=data-migration-source-instance.asasasas.eu-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;"
                        "Database=sourcedb;"
                        "uid=source;pwd=source1234")
```

Any points on how to query RDS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting means that the lambda doesn't have the `pyodbc` module.

You should read up on dependency management in AWS Lambda. There are basically two strategies for including dependencies with your deployment - [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) or zip with the [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html).

If you're using the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) then [`Serverless-python-requirements`](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) is an excellent package for managing your dependencies and lets you choose your dependency management strategy with minimal changes to your application.

Answer (score 1):

you need to upload the dependencies of the lambda along with the code. If you deploy your lambda manually (i.e. create a zip file / right from the console), you will need to attach the `pyodb` library. (More information is available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies).

If you're using any other deployment tool (serverless, SAM, chalice), it will be much easier: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements, https://aws.github.io/chalice/topics/packaging.html#rd-party-packages, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's my github repo with automated builds of the the ODBC 18 drivers for Python 3.11 and 3.12. Prebuilt packages and Dockerfile for x86_64 and ARM64

https://github.com/davidcomerford/pyodbc-mssql-lambda-layer

I like to pull the latest version of unixodbc from Amazons repo. This feels a lot safer than everyone else's fixed versions, security, bugfixes, etc.